# security-constraint and welcome-file

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets, web.xml

In my web.xml I use something like this:

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Block all</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Allow facelets</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

All incoming requests are blocked except for those which start with /faces/.
I do so because, otherwise, unauthorized users could access to facelets source files.

It works fine but it doesn't show welcome file because even the root path is blocked.
I tried to add `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to second security-constraint but nothing.

Comment: I'm the only one who have this kind of problem! Is there an alternative way to protect facelets source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, map the `FacesServlet` on the suffix pattern instead. When you're still on JSF 1.x, map it on `*.jsf`. Then you can just block access on `*.xhtml` with that security constraint. When you're already on JSF 2.0 (your question history confirms this), just map it on `*.xhtml`. In contrary to in JSF 1.x, the `FacesServlet` won't run in an infinite loop with that. This way you don't need any security constraint at all. The only con is that you won't be able to serve "plain vanilla" XHTML files without involving the `FacesServlet`. But doing so wouldn't make any sense anyway, such a file has to be served as `*.html` anyway.

PS: Thank you for providing another reason why the `/faces/*` prefix pattern sucks ;)

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine but it doesn't show welcome file because even the root
>   path is blocked. I tried to add / to second
>   security-constraint but nothing.

In this case, it should have worked. I tested it in my machine, it doesn't work the first time. until, we restart the application server. then it behaves as expected.

Comment: Oh, and we updated our web.xml: our <welcome-file-list> was <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>, we updated it to <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>